# What exactly does it mean for a programming language to be simple?

Tags: programming-languages, software-design

What factors are important? How do you know if a given programming language is "simple" or "simpler" than another language?

Comment: Questions that are mostly meant to create discussion rather than fact-based answers are off topic here. Please review the [tour] and look through the [help] for more information on what kinds of things you should and shouldn't ask here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a fair question to ask, since different languages serve different purposes and it might not really be comparing apples to apples.

However, with that said, memory management would come to mind.  One can argue that Java is a "simpler" language than C++, since it has a garbage collector that can deal with some of the complexities around memory management, instead of forcing you to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In my perspective, these are the points that define the complexity of a language.

1. Variation of syntax from common pseudocode and constructs
2. Ease of developing a structure for real-life entities like objects
3. Methods of structure enforcement at compile time.
4. Memory management strategy allocation/deallocation
5. Code reusability
6. Ease of code headers and directives management
7. Inbuilt libraries
8. Relative installation package sizes
9. Data exchange capabilities like over network of files
10. Process handling like thread management
11. Relative brevity of the code
12. Speed of compilation
13. Developer community size and documentation
14. OpenSource implementations
15. Platform dependence

And many more could be added to this list.